# How to flatten down a nested model in backbone.js?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, nested-loops

I have a nested model like this:

```
ProgramGuide
    |-channels
        |-channel
            |-programs
```

Now I want to get the very last ending program regardless of channels.

In the `ProgramGuide` model I have a method:

```
lastProgram : function(){
   //how to find last ending program?    
}
```

**So, is there a good way to find the last ending program, maybe a way to flatten down the model tree for programs, or must I write a nested loop to achieve this?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do know that backbone depends on underscore, so you always have underscore methods available
i don't have any exact code example, but i'm sure you don't need to nest loops to run through your structure,

i bet you can use any of these underscore methods,

- [underscore flatten](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#flatten) possibly to flatten your structure (can get hard, because you get the normal model attributes with it, should need a workaround to only have the .toJSON() of each model
- [underscore filter](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#filter) could be used to filter out the attributes itself only, or to filter the program list
- [underscore sortBy](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#sortBy) could be used to sort on your air time, to get the last ending program
- [underscore pluck](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#pluck) could be used to pluck only the ID, name and ending time, to remove all the clutter in your structure

i will try to come up with an example, later today
but i can't promise when i have time for it.